# How to open csv File in Jupyter Notebook from Jupyterhub Files?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In my Jupyterhub I have a csv File Test. The directory is /home/abc/Test.csv.

How can I get this csv File in my Jupyter Notebook?

I have tried the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

from os.path import expanduser
full_path = os.path.expanduser('/home/abc/Test.csv')

df1 = pd.read_csv(full_path)
print(df1)
```

But I is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the expanduser() function properly.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path= os.path.expanduser('~\abc\test.csv')

df1 = pd.read_csv(path)
print(df1)
```